# Server side data conversions

Tags: console, server-side, data-conversion

I have created an console app and deployed it in the server. Running via Task Scheduler.

I have tested this code on my machine:

```
string qty = "-3.00"
decimal itemQty = 0;
itemQty = Math.Abs(Convert.ToDecimal(qty));
```

> Returns: 3.00

However, upon deployment to server, the same code

> Returns: 300.00

Why is that?

I know for dates I can do `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Can I develop a workaround for this?

Comment: You should include in your question the critical information that the default culture on your development machine is not the same as the culture on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Added `CultureInfo` for `Convert.ToDecimal`

```
itemQty = Math.Abs(Convert.ToDecimal(qty, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```